# Save changes back to database using entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have simple query that loads data from two tables into GUI. I'm saving loaded data to widely available object `Clients currentlySelectedClient`.

```
using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM()) 
{
   currentlySelectedClient = context.Kliencis.Include("Podmioty").FirstOrDefault(d => d.KlienciID == klientId);
   if (currentlySelectedClient != null) 
   {
      textImie.Text = currentlySelectedClient.Podmioty.PodmiotOsobaImie;
      textNazwisko.Text = currentlySelectedClient.Podmioty.PodmiotOsobaNazwisko;
   } 
   else 
   {
      textNazwa.Text = currentlySelectedClient.Podmioty.PodmiotFirmaNazwa;
   }
}
```

So now if I would like to:

1) Save changes made by user how do I do it? Will I have to prepare something on database side? How do I handle modifying multiple tables (some data goes here, some there)? My current code seems to write .KlienciHaslo just fine, but it doesn't affect Podmioty at all. I tried different combinations but no luck.

2) Add new client to database (and save information to related tables as well)?

```
    currentClient.Podmioty.PodmiotOsobaImie = textImie.Text;  // not saved
    currentClient.Podmioty.PodmiotOsobaNazwisko = textNazwisko.Text; // not saved
    currentClient.KlienciHaslo = "TEST111"; // saved

    using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM()) 
    {
        var objectInDB = context.Kliencis.SingleOrDefault(t => t.KlienciID == currentClient.KlienciID);
        if (objectInDB != null) 
        {
           // context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(currentClient.Podmioty, EntityState.Modified);
           //context.Podmioties.Attach(currentClient.Podmioty);
           context.Kliencis.ApplyCurrentValues(currentClient); // update current client
           //context.ApplyCurrentValues("Podmioty", currentClient.Podmioty); // update current client
        } 
        else 
        {
           context.Kliencis.AddObject(currentClient);  // save new Client
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
     }
```

How can I achieve both?

Edit for an answer (doesn't save anything ):

```
currentClient.Podmioty.PodmiotOsobaImie = textImie.Text; // no save
currentClient.Podmioty.PodmiotOsobaNazwisko = textNazwisko.Text; // no save
currentClient.KlienciHaslo = "TEST1134"; // no save

using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM()) 
{
    if (context.Kliencis.Any(t => t.KlienciID == currentClient.KlienciID)) 
    {
        context.Kliencis.Attach(currentClient); // update current client
    } 
    else 
    {
        context.Kliencis.AddObject(currentClient);  // save new Client
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Good question. Does it still not work when you uncomment the line `context.Podmioties.Attach(currentClient.Podmioty);`?

Comment: It shoots me some errors. I tried couple of combinations but gave up with errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently [ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx) only works with scalar properties.

If you *attach* the `currentClient` then associated objects should also attach, which means they'll be updated when you `SaveChanges()`

**But** you'll get an `Object with the key exists` exception because you are already loading the object from the database into the `objectInDB` variable. The context can only contain one copy of a Entity, and it knows that `currentClient` is the same as `objectInDB` so throws an exception.

Try this pattern instead

```
if (context.Kliencis.Any(t => t.KlienciID == currentClient.KlienciID)) 
{
    context.Kliencis.Attach(currentClient); // update current client
} 
else 
{
    context.Kliencis.AddObject(currentClient);  // save new Client
}
```

or if you're using an identity as the ID, then

```
// if the ID is != 0 then it's an existing database record
if (currentClient.KlienciID != 0) 
{
    context.Kliencis.Attach(currentClient); // update current client
} 
else // the ID is 0; it's a new record
{
    context.Kliencis.AddObject(currentClient);  // save new Client
}
```

Comment: `An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.` is an error when I remove my ApplyCurrentValues and put yours attach.

Comment: Ah, that's because you're retrieving it first. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried the 1st proposed solution and it didn't save anything (as per code i've updated the main question with the code I used).

Comment: I managed to get the correct solution with your help. I had to use ChangeObjectState for Entity to save changes.

Answer (score 1):

After some work and help from Kirk about the ObjectStateManager error that I was getting I managed to fix this. This code allows me to save both changes to both tables.

```
 currentClient.Podmioty.PodmiotOsobaImie = textImie.Text;
 currentClient.Podmioty.PodmiotOsobaNazwisko = textNazwisko.Text;
 currentClient.KlienciHaslo = "TEST1134";
 using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM()) {
       if (context.Kliencis.Any(t => t.KlienciID == currentClient.KlienciID)) {
           context.Podmioties.Attach(currentClient.Podmioty);
           context.Kliencis.Attach(currentClient);
           context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(currentClient.Podmioty, EntityState.Modified);
           context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(currentClient, EntityState.Modified);
        } else {
           context.Kliencis.AddObject(currentClient);  // save new Client
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
  }
```